# Python & Selenium : Scroll down to avoid overlaping advertising and click button

Tags: python, selenium

I try to loop through pages but I have overlaping advertising on my numbers of pages button.

I have this on my browser, the pages buttons are behind this "DocuSign" advertising:

[image]

So I tried to scroll down to be able to click on next page but it doesn't work.

I would like to have this to be able to click on next pages:

[image]

I tried this:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/name/Downloads/chromedriver 4")
url = 'http://www.legorafi.fr/category/france/politique'
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div#appconsent>iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button--filled>span.baseText"))).click()

page_number = 1
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(3)
    try: 
        link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[5]/div/a[1]')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
    link.click()
    print(driver.current_url)
    page_number += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try finding the next page button more appropriately instead.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Next Page')]")
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a better solution. More easy to use